# Is there a way to use Pandas UDF in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a complex Pandas UDF implementation which works perfectly in PySpark. Now, I need to migrate it to use in Spark Scala. Is there a way I can directly use the current UDF implementation? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you migrating to Scala if you want to keep your Python code? I would say: stick with one language, don't mix if you can avoid it.

Comment: No, you have to reinterpret your logic with the Scala concepts